# Regarding docker daemon to spawn containers in a custom CIDR block

Tags: linux, docker, lxc

I have a use case in which i want to spawn docker containers in a different CIDR block. At this point I have created my own custom image. Now I created a new bridge as follows:-

```
service docker stop
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip addr add MYCIDRBLOCK dev br0
ip link set br0 up
docker -d -b br0
```

So far so good, the daemon gave the following output:-

```
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock) 
INFO[0000] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver "devicemapper" 
WARN[0000] Running modprobe bridge nf_nat failed with message: , error: exit     status 1 
INFO[0000] Loading containers: start.                   
........................
INFO[0000] Loading containers: done.                    
INFO[0000] Daemon has completed initialization          
INFO[0000] Docker daemon                                 commit=0baf609     execdriver=native-0.2 graphdriver=devicemapper version=1.7.0
```

Now i try to start my docker container with all ports exposed:-

```
docker run -d -i -t -expose 1-59999 arunav/myimage /bin/bash
```

On client side I get:-

```
 Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 1d29cf0d8057fd62bae9e45e5a91968b675a6c43e115f7912dd00abb05d90dd9: invalid argument
```

On server side i get the following info:-

```
ERRO[0042] leaving endpoint failed: a container has already joined the endpoint 
ERRO[0042] Handler for POST /containers/{name:.*}/start returned error:   Cannot start container  1d29cf0d8057fd62bae9e45e5a91968b675a6c43e115f7912dd00abb05d90dd9: invalid argument 
ERRO[0042] HTTP Error                                    err=Cannot start container 1d29cf0d8057fd62bae9e45e5a91968b675a6c43e115f7912dd00abb05d90dd9: invalid argument statusCode=500
```

So at first I thought that some previous container is hogging some endpoint. So I ran this command to get rid of container dumps:-

```
 docker ps -a -q | xargs -n 1 -I {} docker rm {}
```

I dont know then what could be the issue. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to add an extra bridge? Did you try to use default bridge with explicit CIDR in `--bip` arg?

> --bip=CIDR — supply a specific IP address and netmask for the docker0 bridge, using standard CIDR notation like 192.168.1.5/24.

(from [here](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#docker0))